# How to display the Google Analytics charts with relative numbers instead of absolute numbers?

Tags: charts, google-analytics

If I want to see which amount of my user base uses a specific browser, I'd like to see that amount in the graph **relative** to the number of sessions or users.

Unfortunately the graph only shows the absolute number of sessions or users and if I add lines for specific browsers, I can't really read the relative amount.

How to configure the graph accordingly?

[GA graph showing absolute number of sessions with specific browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExRkp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Audience/Technology/Browser & OS, then the percentage of person using a specific browser is indicated in brackets. It won't be displayed in the graph, but you get the percentage. 
I hope it helps.

Regards,

Mat

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately you can't see the percentage over time as you can see the number of sessions over time. I would want to switch the x-axis of the graph from "absolute number" to "percentage" ;-)